# Form is not showing after using Ajax call

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to show the form using Ajax call but it is not working.
Please check my code below.

## views/users/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Enter your data<h1>
    <%= link_to 'New Task', users_new_path, remote: true %>
    <div id="task-form" style="display:none;"></div>
```

## users/new.html.erb

```
<%= render 'form' %>
```

## users/new.js.erb

```
$('#task-form').html("<%= j (render 'form') %>");
$('#task-form').slideDown(350);
```

## users/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for :user, remote: true do |f|   %>
  <%= f.input  :name %>
  <%= f.input  :content %>
  <%= f.button :submit  %>
<% end %>
```

## controller/users_controller.rb

```
  class UsersController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @user=User.all
     respond_to do |format|
    format.html
    format.js
    end
   end
    def new
        @user=User.new
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.js
        end
    end
    def create

    end
end
```

## routes.rb

```
Ajax3::Application.routes.draw do
  root :to => "users#index"
  get "users/new" => "users#new"
  post "users/create" => "users#create"
end
```

In my browser console after click on the link i am getting the following error.

Error:

```
    GET http://localhost:3000/users/new 500 (Internal Server Error)
    jQuery.ajaxTransport.send   @   jquery.js?body=1:9632
jQuery.extend.ajax  @   jquery.js?body=1:9177
$.rails.rails.ajax  @   jquery_ujs.js?body=1:84
$.rails.rails.handleRemote  @   jquery_ujs.js?body=1:164
(anonymous function)    @   jquery_ujs.js?body=1:342
jQuery.event.dispatch   @   jquery.js?body=1:4642
jQuery.event.add.elemData.handle    @   jquery.js?body=1:4310
```

I am using the rails version 3.2.19.

Comment: What do you see in browsers console? Can you post that and also can you post your logs?

Comment: Mandeep,I am getting like this Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)

Comment: Ahh need full information so can you edit you question and post full logs when you click on that link and also what you see in browsers console?

Comment: That is odd. Does the form gets render when you send a HTML request by browser?

Answer (score 0):

Update Code:

> 1) Path is wrong "users_new_path" to "new_users_path"

views/users/index.html.erb

```
<h1>Enter your data<h1>
    <%= link_to 'New Task', new_users_path, remote: true %>
    <div id="task-form" style="display:none;"></div>
```

> ```
> 2) Update users/new.js.erb
> ```

```
$('#task-form').html("<%= escape_javascript(render("form"))  %>");
$('#task-form').slideDown(350);
```

> 3) Update:controller/users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @user=User.new
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html
            format.json
        end
    end
    def create

    end
end
```